# What is the use of '#' character in jhipster urls?

Tags: angular, jhipster

In standard angular applications, there isn't a '#' sign in urls. What is the use of '#' character in jhipster urls? How is this character added to the url?

Comment: they might be using the `HashLocationStrategy ` of Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular front end of a JHipster app is using the [hashlocationstrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy) e.g.  [the front end of jhipster-registry app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=useHash&type=)